# Radius of convergence of a complex power series question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

I know the general idea for ROC (radius of convergence) is to use the ratio test, or lim sup, however how would i go about solving this?

Comment: What ratio would you use for the ratio test?

Comment: i attempted $|{\frac{(2^{n+1}+i)(z-i)^{n+1}}{(2^n+i)(z-i)^n}}|$

Comment: Correct, what limit did you get?  (These are things to put into your question...)

Comment: i cancelled that down to $|(z-i)|<\frac{1}{2}$ therefore R= $\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of convergence of $\,\sum a_nz^n\,$ is also the supremum of the $r\ge 0$ such that $\lvert a_n\rvert\, r^n$ tends to $0$. Now $\lvert a_n\rvert=\lvert 2^n+i\rvert\sim_\infty 2^n$, hence:
$$\lvert a_n\rvert\, r^n\sim_\infty (2r)^n$$
which tends to $0$ if and only if $2r<1$. We conclude  the radius of convergence is equal to $\dfrac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\root{n}\of{|2^n + i|} \to 2$ as $n\to\infty$.  Use the root test.